# CSS Inline styling for properties not GLOBALLY used

Tags: css

I don't want to argue regarding the use of inline styles over external styles however I just want to know your ideas on certain situations wherein inline styling could be used.

For example I have 10 types of tables that have different width but always use the same border color, thickness and padding. What I currently think is I should declare a global CSS class that controls the border and the padding of the table and then use inline styling to specify the width of the table.

E.g
<table class="default" style="width: 320px;">

Is my approach applicable?

Comment: Why do you think inline styles should be globally used...?

Comment: What I was trying to explain is to set some GLOBAL CSS properties on a CSS class and then do inline styling on the <tables> to specify their width. I have HTML pages with tables that have different width. Is this a right approach regarding this thought? I'm thinking of having an easy way to update my tables specifically their width.

Answer (score 0):

yes u can declare a global CSS class and use this in all table. it will work for all table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding something here. If you take this:

```
<table class = "default" style = "width: 320px;">
```

Then this does **not** apply `width: 320px;` on all `table`s with class `default`. It only applies it on this specific element which has the `style` attribute.

If you're looking to specify such CSS without having to `<link>` external files, you can embed your CSS within [`<style>`](http://www.htmlquick.com/reference/tags/style.html) tags:

```
.default { //or table, or whatever your selector is
    width: 320px;
}
```

If you want to style a particular table with the class `default` with a different `width`, give it another class (`class = "default width320"`) and do:

```
.default.width320 { //selects element with BOTH default and width320 classes
    width: 320px;
}
```

[Read more about CSS selectors here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/selectorref), and [selector specificity here](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity).

---

**Edit:** if you only want to style that particular table, your approach is relatively-fine. But, I suggest using classes and merging your styles in one place (whether it's a `.css` file or an inline `<style>` definition) — it's much more maintainable and tidier than scattered `style` attribute definitions.

**Edit 2:** it's absolutely **correct** to use `style` attributes. It's more of a matter of personal choice. If you're sure that this won't cause maintainability issues (`'Hey, why is my table 320 pixels wide? I don't see anything in my CSS file that does that'`), then go for it. It's what the `style` attribute is for.

Comment: yes, I'm not trying to specify a fixed width on my table CSS class rather declare GLOBAL properties. My idea is to use the GLOBAL property and then specify the width of a certain table using inline styling

Comment: yes, I get your point. However is it correct for instance a CSS property is just to be used once in a site, then inline styling can be done? Or it's really a must to always use external CSS

Comment: @mangeb00x It's absolutely correct and fine to use inline CSS — it's more of a matter of personal choice whether to actually use it or not. If you're sure that this won't cause maintainability issues (`'Hey, why is my table 320 pixels wide? I don't see anything in my CSS file that does that'`), then go for it. It's what the `style` attribute is for.

See my edit.

Comment: ok, thanks. Just one more question, what if a person who's not knowledgeable in CSS would do HTML page updates on the tables I'm referring; for instance change the width of a table? Since for me it would be very easy for those not-so-technical-guys to do the updates since they will only change the width using the "style" attribute. What do you think? This "ease of updates" is the requirement I'm currently weighing. However I do get your point about the use of the external CSS, I'm just thinking that those types of users would have some difficulty (probably a training will help them, right?)

Comment: @mangeb00x Oh. Well, that's indeed a problem. Perhaps you should add a [comment](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/ht/how_to_comment_html.htm) just near the `<table>` definition, pointing people to a CSS file/`<style>` definition where they can change the width.

If you think your teammates/other-guys would not respect that, just go for inline styles, since they are indeed clearest in this case.

Comment: ok, I'll just discuss this issue with my team leader. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe its a correct approach in your case. As you are making the correct use of external class "default", by using it in all the tables and specifying the different widths inline with the specific elements.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a problem because, most of the time, if you've done it once then you're going to want to do it again.  And now you have two identical `style` properties.  And, well, they should both be red-bordered.  Oh, and I need a third one of these tables somewhere.  And, wait, they should be a little skinnier...

On the other hand, if you used a one-off class, you can just slap it on the next table.  Or you can compare all ten tables and tweak them from one place, etc.

The problem with violating principles is that principles are often hard-earned.  :)